# Error "items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope" when trying to use a trait from an imported crate's struct

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to implement a function:

```
extern crate num_bigint as bigint;

use bigint::{BigUint};

fn encode(bytes: BigUint) -> Vec<char> {

    // determine padding length
    let num_bits = bytes.bits();
    let padding: bool = num_bits % 6 != 0;
    let num_chars: usize = num_bits / 6;

    let bitmask = BigUint::parse_bytes(b"7", 16);

    let mut base64_chars: Vec<char> = Vec::new();

    for idx in num_chars..0 {
        let shifted = bytes << (num_chars * 6);
        use BigUint;
        let c = shifted.to_u8();
    }

    return base64_chars;
}
```

it fails on `let c = shifted.to_u8()`

> no method named `to_u8` found for type `bigint::BigUint` in the current scope. 
>   method not found in `bigint::BigUint`. 
>   help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope

Coming from a c++ background I'm having more of a struggle with learning Rust than I expected. What is that help text trying to let me know? I tried adding `using BigUint` before the line, but that just states I'm doing something redundant. How do I get to use this trait?

Comment: If you read the entire error message, it should contain a hint about what to add to solve this problem. Specifically, it should tell you to add `use num_traits::cast::ToPrimitive`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't see that in the error message. All I got were ideas for other types that the trait was implemented for (```std::box::Boxed```, etc). That fixed the issue though, thanks! What did that do that resolved the problem?

Comment: You can see in the documentation for `BigUint` [here](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.2.3/num_bigint/struct.BigUint.html#impl-ToPrimitive) that the `to_u8` method is part of the `ToPrimitive` trait. Methods from traits can only be used when the traits are in scope. (This is what the "help:" part of your error message refers to.) Also I got the error message by [attempting to compile your code in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c4bf36330fed11e0e5667b412c8d4cb), which gives the hint about `ToPrimitive`.

Comment: Ah I see, ToPrimitive was the trait that I wasn't including. I was compiling using MSVC on VSCode and didn't have that very useful information. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

From @Frxstrem's helpful comment!

Importing the crate num-traits and doing the following fixed this:

```
        use num_traits::cast::ToPrimitive;
        let c = shifted.to_u8();
```